# Why sorting a pandas column causing reordering the sub-groups?

Tags: pandas

The goal of my question is to understand why this happens and if this is a defined behaviour. I need to know to design my unittests in a predictable way. I **do not** want or need to change that behaviour or work around it.

Here is the initial data on the left side complete and on the right side just all `ID.eq(1)` but the order is the same as you can see in the index and the `val` column.

```
|    |   ID | val   |      |    |   ID | val   |                               
|---:|-----:|:------|      |---:|-----:|:------|                               
|  0 |    1 | A     |      |  0 |    1 | A     |                               
|  1 |    2 | B     |      |  3 |    1 | x     |                               
|  2 |    9 | C     |      |  4 |    1 | R     |                               
|  3 |    1 | x     |      |  6 |    1 | G     |                               
|  4 |    1 | R     |      |  9 |    1 | a     |                               
|  5 |    4 | F     |      | 12 |    1 | d     |                               
|  6 |    1 | G     |      | 13 |    1 | e     |                               
|  7 |    9 | H     |                                     
|  8 |    4 | I     |                                     
|  9 |    1 | a     |                                     
| 10 |    2 | b     |                                     
| 11 |    9 | c     |                                     
| 12 |    1 | d     |                                     
| 13 |    1 | e     |                                     
| 14 |    4 | f     |                                     
| 15 |    2 | g     |                                     
| 16 |    9 | h     |                                     
| 17 |    9 | i     |                                     
| 18 |    4 | X     |                                     
| 19 |    5 | Y     |
```

This right table is also the result I would **expected** when doing the following:
When I sort by `ID` the order of the rows inside the subgroups (e.g. `ID.eq(1)`) is modified. Why is it so?

This is the **unexpected** result

```
|    |   ID | val   |
|---:|-----:|:------|
|  0 |    1 | A     |
| 13 |    1 | e     |
| 12 |    1 | d     |
|  6 |    1 | G     |
|  9 |    1 | a     |
|  3 |    1 | x     |
|  4 |    1 | R     |
```

This is a full MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

# initial data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ID': [1, 2, 9, 1, 1, 4, 1, 9, 4, 1,
               2, 9, 1, 1, 4, 2, 9, 9, 4, 5],
        'val': list('ABCxRFGHIabcdefghiXY')
    }
)
print(df.to_markdown())

# only the group "1"
print(df.loc[df.ID.eq(1)].to_markdown())

# sort by 'ID'
df = df.sort_values('ID')
# only the group "1" (after sorting)
print(df.loc[df.ID.eq(1)].to_markdown())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) documentation, the [stability of the sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) is not always guaranteed depending on the chosen algorithm:

```
kind : {'quicksort', 'mergesort', 'heapsort', 'stable'}, default 'quicksort'
     Choice of sorting algorithm. See also :func:`numpy.sort` for more
     information. `mergesort` and `stable` are the only stable algorithms. For
     DataFrames, this option is only applied when sorting on a single
     column or label.
```

If you want to ensure using a stable sort:

```
df.sort_values('ID', kind='stable')
```

output:

```
   ID val
0   1   A
3   1   x
4   1   R
6   1   G
9   1   a
...
```